# cx_freeze QtWebKit import error

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, cx-freeze

My cx_freeze build was working correctly until I added one QWebView element into window. This means I should import QtWebKit, right? On Linux everything works perfectly. On Windows, if I run main.py file everything works perfectly.

If I freeze it into an .exe, this is the [error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsAlm.jpg) . This is my install.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes=["re","PyQt4.QtWebKit"]

exe = Executable(
    script="main.pyw",
    base="Win32GUI",
    targetName = "LEX.exe"
    )

setup(
    name = "blabla",
    version = "1.3",
    description = "My application",
    options = {"build_exe": {"includes":includes}},
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

I am building it on x64 Windows 7, but with x86 versions of PyQt4 and Python3.2 x86. Before that QWebView element there were no problems at all.

Comment: What version of PyQt4 do you have? There is apparently [a problem like this that was fixed in 4.8.4](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/issues/detail?id=237). Also, if you don't already have the latest version of cx_Freeze, you could try updating that.

Comment: Both Linux and Windows versions of PyQt are 4.9.4, cx_freeze version is 4.2.3. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Note there's a newer version of cx_Freeze you could try (4.3). If that doesn't work, you could try asking the [cx_Freeze mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/cx-freeze-users).

Comment: Your answer helped me. I installed cx_freeze 4.3 and edited the imports a little bit, which was also needed. Imports are now like this: 
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView,QWebPage

and it works :) Thank you once more.

Comment: You're welcome. Stackoverflow should let you post and accept your own answer, so it's clear that the problem got solved.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading to cx_freeze 4.3 and editing the imports did the trick. Imports are now like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView,QWebPage
```

Comment: got "No module named QtNetwork" too. adding "from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *", it works!

Answer (score 1):

You should not add imports (and possibly pollute your namespace) just to have cx_Freeze recognize the dependency.
Rather add PyQt4.QtNetwork to your "includes" list as you did with PyQt4.QtWebKit.
You can also include all modules of a package by using the "packages" option. That is, "packages" is for whole packages what "includes" is for modules.